# how to select value if key is uuid in mongodb

Tags: mongodb-query

the mongodb data like this:

```json
{
  "_id": "123dsadasfa454sdsaw",
  "hashmap": {
    "uuid-12sadsadw5": {
      "name": "bob"
    },
    "uuid-12sadsadwew5": {
      "name": "alice"
    }
  },
  "age": 10
}
```

"hashmap" like java HashMap, the key is uuid like "uuid-12sadsadwew5" and the value is object.
I want to  get the data which the name in  "hashmap" value is not null. And I use sql :

```
db.tabl1.find({"hashmap.values.name":{$ne:null}})
```

but  cannot get the right result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First use `$objectToArray` to create an array with values `k` and `v`. As we don't know the key (`k`) we can search by value (`v`).
- Then `$unwind` array
- And `$match` values where name is not null.
- And then regroup and recreate the object using `$arrayToObject`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "hashmap": {
        "$objectToArray": "$hashmap"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$hashmap"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "hashmap.v.name": {
        "$ne": null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "hashmap": {
        "$push": "$hashmap"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "hashmap": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$hashmap"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VJMzVf-ymd-)