# How to get only specific nested object from MongoDB collection where uuid is used as key

Tags: mongodb

I only want this matched object in query result, by querying uuid "630c260e333c41549c43cae5f8e626d5":

```
        {
          "enableAnnotations": false,
          "enableMultipleFilesUpload": true,
          "enableWorkflows": true,
          "formSectionID": "a9bcde7f8fc14e519965a655d9574fb7",
          "isThumbnailField": false,
          "label": "WD multi upload Ttl in Dup Section DW",
          "publishToFolder": false,
          "publishWhenApproved": false,
          "type": "upload",
          "uuid": "630c260e333c41549c43cae5f8e626d5"
        }
```

from the following Collection document:

```
[{
  "_id": "07672b703cc44ce6887159984911dd6e",
  "createTime": "2022-06-21T12:08:00Z",
  "creator": "75e5d59fa1be0f932bff8407536730d0",
  "defination": {
    "fields": {
      "a9bcde7f8fc14e519965a655d9574fb7": [
        {
          "enableAnnotations": false,
          "enableMultipleFilesUpload": true,
          "enableWorkflows": true,
          "formSectionID": "a9bcde7f8fc14e519965a655d9574fb7",
          "isThumbnailField": false,
          "label": "WD multi upload Ttl in Dup Section DW",
          "publishToFolder": false,
          "publishWhenApproved": false,
          "type": "upload",
          "uuid": "630c260e333c41549c43cae5f8e626d5"
        },
        {
          "enableAnnotations": false,
          "enableMultipleFilesUpload": false,
          "formSectionID": "a9bcde7f8fc14e519965a655d9574fb7",
          "isThumbnailField": false,
          "label": "WD single upload in Dup section DW",
          "publishToFolder": false,
          "type": "upload",
          "uuid": "1aecb33709434d9b9a0cb455c67e2295"
        }
      ],
      "eda3ce9883a14b948eae5b053f720227": [
        {
          "enableAnnotations": false,
          "enableMultipleFilesUpload": true,
          "enableWorkflows": true,
          "formSectionID": "eda3ce9883a14b948eae5b053f720227",
          "isThumbnailField": false,
          "label": "WD upload multi",
          "publishToFolder": false,
          "publishWhenApproved": false,
          "type": "upload",
          "uuid": "e88a097621cc44c4bb440902006f5a12"
        },
        {
          "formSectionID": "eda3ce9883a14b948eae5b053f720227",
          "label": "WD Txt Fld Ttl",
          "type": "text",
          "uuid": "e1bf361509364718b9d52e65cbc292de",
        },
        {
          "enableAnnotations": false,
          "enableMultipleFilesUpload": true,
          "enableWorkflows": true,
          "formSectionID": "eda3ce9883a14b948eae5b053f720227",
          "isThumbnailField": false,
          "label": "WD 2nd-multi-upload",
          "publishToFolder": false,
          "publishWhenApproved": false,
          "type": "upload",
          "uuid": "fbee1d1adf224712a90f3f37b8395aa0"
        },
        {
          "enableAnnotations": true,
          "enableMultipleFilesUpload": false,
          "formSectionID": "eda3ce9883a14b948eae5b053f720227",
          "isThumbnailField": false,
          "label": "WD single upload Ttl DW",
          "publishToFolder": false,
          "type": "upload",
          "uuid": "5504ce66d1bc4f659eefed4df4e73b99",
        }
      ]
    },
    "sections": {
      "291b58eddee04a05bd8e7d80d99241b9": [
        {
          "uuid": "eda3ce9883a14b948eae5b053f720227"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "a9bcde7f8fc14e519965a655d9574fb7"
        }
      ]
    },
    "tabs": [
      {
        "uuid": "291b58eddee04a05bd8e7d80d99241b9"
      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

After some research, I used the query: (by referring [how to select value if key is uuid in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69302432/how-to-select-value-if-key-is-uuid-in-mongodb))

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "fields": {
        "$objectToArray": "$defination.fields"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$fields"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "fields.v.uuid": "630c260e333c41549c43cae5f8e626d5",
      "fields.v.enableWorkflows": true,
      "fields.v.enableMultipleFilesUpload": true,
      "fields.v.type": "upload"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "fields": {
        "$push": "$fields"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "fields": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$fields"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

and I got the result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "07672b703cc44ce6887159984911dd6e",
    "fields": {
      "a9bcde7f8fc14e519965a655d9574fb7": [
        {
          "enableAnnotations": false,
          "enableMultipleFilesUpload": true,
          "enableWorkflows": true,
          "formSectionID": "a9bcde7f8fc14e519965a655d9574fb7",
          "isThumbnailField": false,
          "label": "WD multi upload Ttl in Dup Section DW",
          "publishToFolder": false,
          "publishWhenApproved": false,
          "type": "upload",
          "uuid": "630c260e333c41549c43cae5f8e626d5"
        },
        {
          "enableAnnotations": false,
          "enableMultipleFilesUpload": false,
          "formSectionID": "a9bcde7f8fc14e519965a655d9574fb7",
          "isThumbnailField": false,
          "label": "WD single upload in Dup section DW",
          "publishToFolder": false,
          "type": "upload",
          "uuid": "1aecb33709434d9b9a0cb455c67e2295"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

But it contains extra sibling objects.

I tried the answer from post but it doesn't work: [How can I get only specific object from nested array mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292288/how-can-i-get-only-specific-object-from-nested-array-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

One option to drill down is using `$reduce` with `$filter`, but first we need known keys, hence the `$objectToArray` which you already have:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {fields: {$objectToArray: "$defination.fields"}}},
  {$project: {res: {
        $first: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$fields",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {$concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                {$filter: {
                    input: "$$this.v",
                    as: "inner",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$inner.uuid",
                        "630c260e333c41549c43cae5f8e626d5"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$ifNull: ["$res", {}]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pu5S2veqdmN)

Comment: To avoid the error when there's no matched record, the final aggregation can be:

$replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$res",
          {}
        ]
      }
    }

Comment: The answer is updated accordingly